# wso2cep: ERROR - 'distance' is neither a function extension nor an aggregated attribute extension in execution plan "ExecutionPlan"

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-cep

I am using WSO2 CEP 4.2.0 version and I am writing an execution plan for checking when coordinates from different sensors do not vary by more than 4 meters, through Siddhi query. But getting an error:  'distance' is neither a function extension nor an aggregated attribute extension in execution plan "ExecutionPlan".

I have installed the GPL - Siddhi Geo Extension, but I do not know why there is that error. Please help me in solving this error.

My execution plan is below:

```
/* Enter a unique ExecutionPlan */
@Plan:name('ExecutionPlan')

/* Enter a unique description for ExecutionPlan */
-- @Plan:description('ExecutionPlan')

/* define streams/tables and write queries here ... */

@Import('SR_ProcessedStream:1.0.0')
define stream srprocessedstream (meta_resultTime long, meta_procedure string, correlation_latitude double, correlation_longitude double);

@Import('MPD_ProcessedStream:1.0.0')
define stream mpdprocessedstream (meta_resultTime long, meta_procedure string, correlation_latitude double, correlation_longitude double);

@Import('GBSS_ProcessedStream:1.0.0')
define stream gbssprocessedstream (meta_resultTime long, meta_procedure string, correlation_latitude double, correlation_longitude double);

@Export('measuredStream:1.0.0')
define stream measuredStream (meta_procedure1 string, meta_procedure2 string);

define table sensorTable(meta_procedure string, correlation_latitude double, correlation_longitude double);

from gbssprocessedstream
select meta_procedure, correlation_latitude, correlation_longitude
insert into sensorTable;

from mpdprocessedstream
select meta_procedure, correlation_latitude, correlation_longitude
insert into sensorTable;

from srprocessedstream
select meta_procedure, correlation_latitude, correlation_longitude
insert into sensorTable;

from gbssprocessedstream join sensorTable
 on sensorTable.meta_procedure != gbssprocessedstream.meta_procedure and 4 > geo : distance (sensorTable.correlation_latitude, sensorTable.correlation_longitude, meta_procedure1.correlation_latitude, meta_procedure1.correlation_longitude)
 select sensorTable.meta_procedure as meta_procedure1, gbssprocessedstream.meta_procedure as meta_procedure2
 insert into measuredStream;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies that the already compiled *p2-repo* that is provided by the [official installation instructions](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/Installing+WSO2+GPL+Features) are not the most up to date and are **missing** the distance function below is an image with the related jar file

[image: geo jar]

In order to use this function you need to [build the p2-repo](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/Installing+WSO2+GPL+Features#InstallingWSO2GPLFeatures-BuildingtheP2repositories(Optional)) and install it and it should work! Once you compile all three projects you should see the p2-repo within directory `wso2-gpl/carbon-event-processing-extensions/repository/target`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

[`distance`](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP420/Geo+Extension#GeoExtension-GeoDistancefunction) is **Function** extension (in contrast to **Stream Processor** extension type).    Please refer [Siddhi Extensions](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP420/Siddhi+Extensions) doc which shows the usage of each of those types.

As mentioned in the above document, function extensions has to be applied on the `select` statement. This error is observed because the function extension is applied elsewhere (in the `join` condition).